# Magento 2 admin end grid module issues?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I have downloaded and installed the magento 2 admin end grid using the following link.

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module

But i am getting errors as shown below while compile:-

```
Errors during compilation:
        Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post
                Incorrect dependency in class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post.php
\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory already exists in context object
        Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save
                Incorrect dependency in class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session already exists in context object
\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory already exists in context object
        Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Edit
                Incorrect dependency in class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Edit in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Edit.php
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session already exists in context object
\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory already exists in context object
```

> I) Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post

**Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml;

abstract class Post extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Post Factory
     * 
     * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory
     */
    protected $_postFactory;

    /**
     * Core registry
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result redirect factory
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $_resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_postFactory           = $postFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry          = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Init Post
     *
     * @return \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post
     */
    protected function _initPost()
    {
        $postId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');
        /** @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post $post */
        $post    = $this->_postFactory->create();
        if ($postId) {
            $post->load($postId);
        }
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('mageplaza_helloworld_post', $post);
        return $post;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve well-formed admin user data from the form input
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::mageplaza_helloworld_post');
    }
}
```

> II) Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Edit

**Edit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\;

class Edit extends \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post
{
    /**
     * Backend session
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_backendSession;

    /**
     * Page factory
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Result JSON factory
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_backendSession    = $backendSession;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $resultRedirectFactory, $context);
    }

    /**
     * is action allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::post');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');
        /** @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post $post */
        $post = $this->_initPost();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::post');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Posts'));
        if ($id) {
            $post->load($id);
            if (!$post->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This Post no longer exists.'));
                $resultRedirect = $this->_resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath(
                    'mageplaza_helloworld/*/edit',
                    [
                        'post_id' => $post->getId(),
                        '_current' => true
                    ]
                );
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        }
        $title = $post->getId() ? $post->getName() : __('New Post');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($title);
        $data = $this->_backendSession->getData('mageplaza_helloworld_post_data', true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $post->setData($data);
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> III)/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php

**Save.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post
{
/**
 * Upload model
 * 
 * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Upload
 */
protected $_uploadModel;

/**
 * File model
 * 
 * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\File
 */
protected $_fileModel;

/**
 * Image model
 * 
 * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\Image
 */
protected $_imageModel;

/**
 * Backend session
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
 */
protected $_backendSession;

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Upload $uploadModel
 * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\File $fileModel
 * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\Image $imageModel
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession
 * @param \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Upload $uploadModel,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\File $fileModel,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\Image $imageModel,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
)
{
    $this->_uploadModel    = $uploadModel;
    $this->_fileModel      = $fileModel;
    $this->_imageModel     = $imageModel;
    $this->_backendSession = $backendSession;
    parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $resultRedirectFactory, $context);
}

/**
 * run the action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('post');
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $data = $this->_filterData($data);
        $post = $this->_initPost();
        $post->setData($data);
        $featuredImage = $this->_uploadModel->uploadFileAndGetName('featured_image', $this->_imageModel->getBaseDir(), $data);
        $post->setFeaturedImage($featuredImage);
        $sampleUploadFile = $this->_uploadModel->uploadFileAndGetName('sample_upload_file', $this->_fileModel->getBaseDir(), $data);
        $post->setSampleUploadFile($sampleUploadFile);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'mageplaza_helloworld_post_prepare_save',
            [
                'post' => $post,
                'request' => $this->getRequest()
            ]
        );
        try {
            $post->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Post has been saved.'));
            $this->_backendSession->setMageplazaHelloWorldPostData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $resultRedirect->setPath(
                    'mageplaza_helloworld/*/edit',
                    [
                        'post_id' => $post->getId(),
                        '_current' => true
                    ]
                );
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
            $resultRedirect->setPath('mageplaza_helloworld/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Post.'));
        }
        $this->_getSession()->setMageplazaHelloWorldPostData($data);
        $resultRedirect->setPath(
            'mageplaza_helloworld/*/edit',
            [
                'post_id' => $post->getId(),
                '_current' => true
            ]
        );
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    $resultRedirect->setPath('mageplaza_helloworld/*/');
    return $resultRedirect;
}

/**
 * filter values
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
protected function _filterData($data)
{
    if (isset($data['sample_multiselect'])) {
        if (is_array($data['sample_multiselect'])) {
            $data['sample_multiselect'] = implode(',', $data['sample_multiselect']);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

}

**Screenshot:-** http://prntscr.com/gqm7xw

Please help me how to fix thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.php**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_backendSession    = $context->getSession();
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $resultRedirectFactory, $context);
    }
```

**Post.php**

```
public function __construct(
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_postFactory           = $postFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry          = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

**save.php file,**

```
public function __construct(
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Upload $uploadModel,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\File $fileModel,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\Image $imageModel,
    \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
)
{
    $this->_uploadModel    = $uploadModel;
    $this->_fileModel      = $fileModel;
    $this->_imageModel     = $imageModel;
    $this->_backendSession = $this->getSession();
    parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $resultRedirectFactory, $context);
}
```

Remove **var/generation** folder and clear cache.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response @Rakesh let me check and get back to you thanks

Comment: @hi Rakesh ji again it showing Incompatible argument type: http://prntscr.com/gqmflx

Comment: display your save.php file code

Comment: Please check now i have added save.php in the above question

Comment: hi @rakesh now i have updated the code

Comment: whats the issue you have faced?

Comment: actually while compile i am getting errors i need to fix it. that's it the module is working fine.